# Reactjs Component with optional/conditional state lifting

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to have a reusable Component that can manage its internal state, but if required by the integrator to also lift it's state (such that it is visible & modifiable by the parent).

I'm sharing with you my current approach but I'm not sure if it's the right/optimum way to do things:

```
function CompChild(props) {
  // Component manages it's own state by default
  const [text, setText] = useState("My default text");
  // If the parent defines it's own property the component will use it      
 useEffect(() => {
    if (props.text !== undefined) {
      setText(props.text);
    }
  }, [props.text]);
  

  // Update the parent state or own internal state 
  //depending on what props the parent sent to us
  const setTextWrapper => (state) {
      if (props.setText !== undefined) {
          props.setText(state)
      } else {
          setText(state)
      }
  }    
....     
}
```

And the caller can decide what flavor to use:

```
function CompParent(props) {
    ..........
    return (<div>
               <CompChild/> // Manages internal state

                <CompChild 
                   text={parentText} 
                   seText={parentSetText}
                /> // Parent Manages the state
            </div>)
}
```

Is this approach/sane?

Are there reasons to avoid doing this by default to all my components?

Do you recommend something else?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mash the two flavors up in a single component.

Instead, I'd keep the low-level component uncontrolled, and then wrap it (maybe with a suitable `forwardRef`, not illustrated below) in a controlled component:

```
function CompChild({ text, onTextChange, ...rest }) {
  // ... uncontrolled ...
  return (
    <input
      {...rest}
      value={text}
      onChange={(e) => onTextChange(e.target.value)}
    />
  );
}

function ControlledCompChild({ initialText, onTextChange }) {
  const [text, setText] = useState(initialText);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialText !== undefined) {
      setText(initialText);
    }
  }, [initialText]);
  const handleTextChange = (text) => {
    setText(text);
    onTextChange(text);
  };
  return <CompChild text={text} onTextChange={handleTextChange} />;
}
```